# Why doesn't the child execute after the fork()? It never gets to child's part of code.

Tags: c, linux, fork, pid

Here is the code I have. I basically want to create a child process that will execute some commands through execvp(). However the program never reaches there as it never prints "Got to child". I dont understand why. Can someone explain what the error is? Because I think I'm following the procedure to the t.

```
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { //if fork() returns less than 1 it failed
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {  //for() returns 0 then this is the child process
        printf("Got to child");
        int exec;
        exec = execvp(args[0], args); /* (2) invoke execvp() */
        if (exec < 0) {
            printf("Error: executing command failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else { //pid>0 therefore this is the parent process
        if (background == 0){
        wait(&status);
        printf("Got to parent");
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post valid, compilable code. also, remove code that is not relevant to the question. after the changes, make sure it still compiles, and reproduces the problem...

Comment: Put a newline in your printf or flush it.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like the typical pattern but I wonder if

```
printf("Got to child");
```

without the \n causes the unwritten buffer to get thrown away when the exec happens and so no output.

Comment: @user3217278 It is not magic, it is called 'line buffered' :-). See ｀setbuf(3)` for further details.

Answer (score 3):

You don't see `Got to child` because you don't include a newline at the end of the message.  If you add the newline, you'll probably suddenly see the message. If you want to be reasonably sure of seeing the output, use a newline at the end of the message.  If you want to be still more sure of doing so, add `fflush(stdout);` or `fflush(0);`.

You don't need to test the return value from `execvp()`.  It only ever returns if it is unsuccessful.  You should report error messages to standard error, not standard output.

Comment: Actually I always do a `fflush(NULL);` just before any `fork` or `execve`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `fflush(NULL)`, flush all streams open for writing…sounds like a good idea.